# Applying proxy for factory class

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, proxy

Is there any disadvantage ior is it discouraged to use proxy on factory class? I am extending from some `Customer\Address` controller and it has some dependencies which I won't use. I want to replace by proxy `\Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked myself this question. Didn't find the proper answer but, I made several conclusions:

- No need to create Proxy for Factory because the factory is not heavy enough. If you would look at any Factory class - you will see, that only object manager passed to the constructor (I don't take into account string with instance name). You can also take a look at the proxy class and ensure there is also only object manager in the constructor. So this to classes is approximately equal by the heaviness. Conclusion - no reason to replace Factory with Factory\Proxy
- Magento doesn't proxied Factory. If you would search in Magento core code you'll find that Magento core team doesn't proxied Factory at all. The only place where I was able to find this in *Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Factory\HtmlContentFactory\Proxy* and honestly I have no idea why...

After this two conclusions, I didn't use the proxy for Factories.

I know it's a little bit late for the answer, but maybe someone else will find this helpful.

Comment: I think it makes sense, especially first argument.